# How to deinitialize a FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

We have a class which derives from FrameworkElement and which is not under our control. 
This class registers eventhandlers in the [OnInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.oninitialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

What is the pattern to properly clean this class up, since FrameworkElement does not provide a counterpart to OnInitialize?

It remains rooted since no part of it removes the EventHandler causing a leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as "deinitializing". Initialization methods are used when it isn't possible to fully initialize an object in its constructor, because it depends on data that isn't available during construction. In these cases construction is broken in two phases: the first step is executed in a parameterless constructor, the second in an initialization method, like `OnInitialize`, after the external data becomes available

What you describe is object disposal, which is performed by calling an object's `Dispose` method. A well-written class should clean up its data, release any external resources *and* release any event handlers.

Visual elements typically have another step in their lifecycle, handled by the OnLoad/OnUnload methods. The Load step occurs when an element is actually placed in XAML view and connected to the other UI elements. Event handlers should be registered in the OnLoad method and removed in the OnUnload method.

If the element has no `Dispose` method , you may be able to raise the Unload event to force the cleanup, although this is a bit of a hack:

```
control.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(FrameworkElement.UloadedEvent))
```

Comment: The class in question is in the AvalonDock library. No concept papers are available justifying the reason why the events are not cleaned up.

Comment: A docking window should only be created once per form. Considering docking is used for the main form of an application, this should only happen once in an application's lifetime. Do you create a lot of forms at runtime? Do you dispose of the forms, reuse them, or leave them to be garbage-collected?

Comment: We are creating ViewModels (and their Views as Anchorables) on demand. Just like Visual Studio does not create all possible windows on startup. LayoutContent has a Closing event and a protected OnClosing to support this. Profilling showed us that closing a window disposed our ViewModel properly, but the following implicit "freeing" of LayoutDocumentPaneGroupControl fails, since it has still active eventhandlers. There is no trace that closing is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Use weak event pattern. In particular, subscribe to events using [`WeakEventManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementations (or, better, its generic version [`WeakEventManager<TEventSource, TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if .NET 4.5 is an option).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted` event.

Add this to the constructor:

```
Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted;
```

And add your cleanup code to this method:

```
private void Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stop();
}
```